# Highlight the search button in key board in blue when typing in it in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard, uisearchbar

How to make the search button in the key board as blue back ground when a user enter the text into the search box.In iphone for search functionality search button in the key board is becoming blue. How to implement this functionality. I think it is possible to do but i don't know... Please help me.

Thank you,
Madan mohan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your xib file in interface builder, then click on your attribute inspector (command-1). Then change this setting:

[image]

Now that I re-read your question maybe you were asking how to implement that search functionality programatically... Is that the case?

EDIT: Ok, if you want to do it programatically then you need to implement UITextInputTraits. Check this documentation out: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html

I think it's going to be a straight-forward copy from the screenshot that I provided.

Comment: @the_great_monkey:Yes, nice guess :)

Comment: Ah ok, so you're happy with doing this in Interface builder as I showed? If so then good!

Comment: @the_great_monkey: No, I need to implement it programatically

Comment: I got it. Just making the boolean yes, shown here. searchTextField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically=YES;